# Using GROUPING to control a totals row

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have the following SQL which gives me a summary table. It's in a Classic ASP page, connecting to an SQL Server Database

```
SELECT D.DOC_TYPE AS 'Doc Type', D.DOC_REF AS 'Doc Ref', 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS2, 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS3, 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS4, 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS5, 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS6, 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS7, 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS8, 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS9, 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS10, 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM IN ('OPS1', 'OPS2', 'OPS3', 'OPS4', 'OPS5') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Div1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM IN ('OPS6', 'OPS7', 'OPS8', 'OPS9', 'OPS10') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Div2, 
SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM Not Like 'OPS%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Other Teams', 
COUNT(D.GUID) AS Total 
FROM DOCUMENT AS D INNER JOIN INTRAY AS I ON I.DOC_GUID = D.GUID 
WHERE D.DOC_TYPE like ? 
AND I.FILE_SYSTEM='B' AND I.MAIL_STATUS IN ('N', 'NT')
GROUP BY D.DOC_TYPE, D.DOC_REF ;
```

This is fine but gives no total row. So I have amended the group by as below

```
GROUP BY D.DOC_TYPE, D.DOC_REF WITH ROLLUP ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

This gives me the total row at the bottom but there is nothing in the first or second column to indicate it's a total row. I would also like to be able to have the total row in bold text in the ASP output.

The whole ASP page is below

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<%' Option Explicit %>  
<!--#include virtual="bactu/IWStats/inc/images_conn.asp"-->
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>I@W Benefits - GIMs Summary</title>
</HEAD><span class="normtext">
<BODY>
<LINK href="../css/images_stats.css" type=text/css rel=stylesheet>
<!--#include virtual="bactu/IWStats/inc/header.asp"-->
<!--#include virtual="bactu/IWStats/inc/menu.asp"-->
<%
'set variables
Dim SQL, RS, cmd
Const adParamInput = 1
Const adDBDate = 133
const adVarWChar = 202

SQL = "SELECT D.DOC_TYPE AS 'Doc Type', D.DOC_REF AS 'Doc Ref', " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS1, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS2, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS3, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS4, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS5, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS6, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS7, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS8, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS9, " & _
    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM='OPS10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPS10, " & _

    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM IN ('OPS1', 'OPS2', 'OPS3', 'OPS4', 'OPS5') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Div1, " & _

    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM IN ('OPS6', 'OPS7', 'OPS8', 'OPS9', 'OPS10') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Div2, " & _

    "SUM(CASE WHEN I.TEAM Not Like 'OPS%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Other Teams', " & _

    "COUNT(D.GUID) AS Total " & _
    "FROM DOCUMENT AS D INNER JOIN INTRAY AS I ON I.DOC_GUID = D.GUID " & _
    "WHERE D.DOC_TYPE like ? " & _
    "AND I.FILE_SYSTEM='B' AND I.MAIL_STATUS IN ('N', 'NT')" & _
    "GROUP BY D.DOC_TYPE, D.DOC_REF WITH ROLLUP ORDER BY 1 DESC ;"


'create recordset
Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.cursortype=adOpenKeyset

'create command
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = IConn
cmd.CommandText = SQL

'Append cmd parameters - CreateParameter(Name, Type, Direction, SizeIfString, Value)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("QueryDocType", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, "GIM%" )

'Initiate recordset from command's execute method
Set RS = cmd.Execute

RS.MoveFirst%>
<br><br>New GIM* / RE_SB docs ;<br><br>
<table border="1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <%For Each fld in rs.Fields%>
           <th><span><%=Server.HTMLEncode(fld.Name)%></span></th>
         <%Next %>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
 <%
   Do Until rs.EOF%>
      <tr>
      <%For Each fld in rs.Fields%>
      <td><%=RS(Server.HTMLEncode(fld.Name))%></th>
      <%Next %>
      </tr>
      <%rs.MoveNext
   Loop%>
   </tbody>
 </table>
<hr>
<%RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing

IConn.Close
Set IConn = Nothing%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Can anyone help? I have read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178544.aspx but it doesn't seem to help. I do not understand how to use the GROUPING function in the SELECt clause properly to acheive what I need.

I've tried to replicate the example given in http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/rollup-and-order-by.html without success.

------ Edit 16/07/14 12:57 -------

I have corrected the SQL as per Gordon Linoff's answer. Can anyone tell me how to amend the table draw so that the last total row is in bold text?

```
Set RS = cmd.Execute
RS.MoveFirst%>
<br><br>New GIM* / RE_SB docs ;<br><br>
<table border="1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <%For Each fld in rs.Fields%>
           <th><span><%=Server.HTMLEncode(fld.Name)%></span></th>
         <%Next %>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
 <%
   Do Until rs.EOF%>
      <tr>
      <%For Each fld in rs.Fields%>
      <td><%=RS(Server.HTMLEncode(fld.Name))%></th>
      <%Next %>   
      </tr>
      <%rs.MoveNext
   Loop%>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: The `null` in the totals row indicates it is a total.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(D.DOC_TYPE, 'Total') AS [Doc Type], D.DOC_REF AS [Doc Ref],
       . . . 
FROM DOCUMENT D INNER JOIN
     INTRAY I
     ON I.DOC_GUID = D.GUID 
WHERE D.DOC_TYPE like ? AND I.FILE_SYSTEM='B' AND I.MAIL_STATUS IN ('N', 'NT')
GROUP BY D.DOC_TYPE, D.DOC_REF WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY D.DOC_TYPE DESC;
```

This replaces the `doc_type` with the string `'Total'`.  NOTE:  this assumes that `DOC_TYPE` is already a string.  If not, convert it to one.  Then the `order by` is changed to refer to the column in the table.  `NULL` values will go at the end with `DESC`.

Also, I recommend that you use single quotes only for string and date constants.  Using them for column aliases is an invitation to future problems.  I replaced those single quotes with square braces.